# ¿Como puedo generar el archivo json correcto?

Tags: json, vb

estoy generando un archivo json desde mi sistema en visual basic atraves de un formulario para poder crear tiendas en mercado pago, la cosa es que estoy creando el json pero de manera incorrecta ya que me están faltando unos corchetes en los días en la propiedad businees del mismo archivo pero no se como poder agregar esos corchetes en la solicitud para poder consumir la api y obtener la respuesta de la misma

Json generado por mi

```
 {
 "name":"TB Puerto Montt",
 "business_hours":{
  "monday":{
     "open":"10:00",
     "close":"20:00"
  },
  "tuesday":{
     "open":"10:00",
     "close":"20:00"
  },
  "wednesday":{
     "open":"10:00",
     "close":"20:00"
  }
 },
 "location":{
  "street_number":"0",
  "street_name":"ILLAPEL ",
  "city_name":"Puerto Montt",
  "state_name":"Los Lagos",
  "latitude":-74.05306,
  "longitude":4.667034,
  "reference":"1234"
 },
 "external_id":"95-105-NB-TI-FN"
 }
```

Archivo Json que me pide la api

```
{
  "name":"CASA MATRZ",
  "business_hours":{
  "monday": [
  {
     "open":"10:00",
     "close":"20:00"
  }
  ],
  "tuesday": [
  {
     "open":"10:00",
     "close":"20:00"
  }
  ],
  "wednesday":[
  {
     "open":"10:00",
     "close":"20:00"
  }
  ]
  },
  "location":{
  "street_number":"0",
  "street_name":"AMERICO ",
  "city_name":"Santiago",
  "state_name":"Antofagasta",
  "latitude":-74.05306,
  "longitude":4.667034,
  "reference":"1234"
 },
 "external_id":"95-99-NB-TI-FN"
}
```

La clase que uso para poder generar el JSON

```
Public Class ClasesJSON
Public Class Rootobject
    Public Property name As String
    Public Property business_hours As Business_Hours
    Public Property location As Location
    Public Property external_id As String
End Class

Public Class Business_Hours
    Public Property monday() As Monday
    Public Property tuesday() As Tuesday
    Public Property wednesday() As Wednesday
    Public Property thursday() As Thursday
    Public Property friday() As Friday
    Public Property saturday() As Saturday
    Public Property sunday() As Sunday
End Class

Public Class Monday
    Public Property open As String
    Public Property close As String
End Class

Public Class Tuesday
    Public Property open As String
    Public Property close As String
End Class

Public Class Wednesday
    Public Property open As String
    Public Property close As String
End Class

Public Class Thursday
    Public Property open As String
    Public Property close As String
End Class

Public Class Friday
    Public Property open As String
    Public Property close As String
End Class

Public Class Saturday
    Public Property open As String
    Public Property close As String
End Class

Public Class Sunday
    Public Property open As String
    Public Property close As String
End Class


Public Class Location
    Public Property street_number As String
    Public Property street_name As String
    Public Property city_name As String
    Public Property state_name As String
    Public Property latitude As Single
    Public Property longitude As Single
    Public Property reference As String
 End Class
End Class
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Objetos y clases

Lo primero, un objeto es una instancia de una `Clase` y una clase es un `tipo`

Digamos que tienes una clase que se llama `UnaClase` y haces esto:

```vb
Dim instanciaClase As UnaClase = New UnaClase()
```

- instanciaClase es el nombre del objeto dado a una unica instancia de `UnaClase`

Con esto claro, sigamos

#### Objetos en JSON

Un objeto tiene la siguiente estructura

```
 "nombre_instancia" : {
   "propiedad_1" : valor,
   "propiedad_2" : valor,
}
```

Notar que las `{}` indican que es un objeto, y obviamente un objeto puede tener propiedades que sean otro objeto.

Entonces digamos que tu tienes:

```
  "monday":{
     "open":"10:00",
     "close":"20:00"
  }
```

Esto indica que tu tienes un objeto cuya instancia se llama `monday` que tiene al menos 2 propiedades del tipo string `open` y `close`

Y si ahora tienes:

```
  "tuesday":{
     "open":"10:00",
     "close":"20:00"
  }
```

Tienes otra instancia llamada `tuesday` que tiene las mismas propiedades, y si tienen las mismas propiedades, podemos suponer que pertenecen a la misma `clase`

Es decir, NO debes crear una clase `monday`, `tuesday`, etc. Debes crear una sola clase (digamos que se llame `Dia`) y cada día es una instancia

#### Array en JSON

Si los objetos vienen encerrados por `{}`, los array vienen encerrados por `[]`

Entonces esto

```
 "monday": [
  {
     "open":"10:00",
     "close":"20:00"
  }
  ]
```

Te indica que hay un  array llamado `monday` del tipo `Dia`

#### Como serían las clases

```
Public Class Rootobject
    Public Property name As String
    Public Property business_hours As Business_Hours
    Public Property location As Location
    Public Property external_id As String
End Class

Public Class Business_Hours
    Public Property monday As Dia()
    Public Property tuesday As Dia()
    Public Property wednesday As Dia()
    Public Property thursday As Dia()
    Public Property friday As Dia()
    Public Property saturday As Dia()
    Public Property sunday As Dia()
End Class

Public Class Dia
    Public Property open As String
    Public Property close As String
End Class

Public Class Location
    Public Property street_number As String
    Public Property street_name As String
    Public Property city_name As String
    Public Property state_name As String
    Public Property latitude As Single
    Public Property longitude As Single
    Public Property reference As String
End Class
```

Por último, ojo que los parentesis para el array deberían ir al final

Tu tienes esto

```
Public Property monday() As Monday
```

y debería ser:

```
Public Property monday As Dia()
```

*A modo de recomendación, si estas trabajando en `.net` te recomiendo usar C#, `VB` es un lenguaje casi muerto porque lo que te va a costar mucho encontrar ayuda, ejemplos y documentación. Al 2023 no tiene mucho sentido usarlo.*

Comment: encontre algo parecido a lo que me comentaste y me funciono gracias igual por tu comentario y ayuda

Comment: Estaba trabajando con C# anteriormente pero donde estoy trabajando ahora es con VB y bueno tengo que adaptarme a esto ya que por ahora no tienen pensado migrar este sistema

Comment: @EduAraneda Buu que horrible situación (me ha pasado). Suerte con el proyecto!!!

Answer (score 0):

El problema que estas teniendo es que no estas definiendo los dias de la semana como listas. Proba algo asi

```
Public Class Business_Hours
    Public Property monday As List(Of Monday)
    Public Property tuesday As List(Of Tuesday)
    Public Property wednesday As List(Of Wednesday)
    Public Property thursday As List(Of Thursday)
    Public Property friday As List(Of Friday)
    Public Property saturday As List(Of Saturday)
    Public Property sunday As List(Of Sunday)
End Class
```

Despues cuando armas el JSON tenes que hacer algo como

```
Dim mondayList As New List(Of Monday)()
mondayList.Add(New Monday With {.open = "10:00", .close = "20:00"})
data.business_hours.monday = mondayList
```

Espero que sirva!